# Creating web services with wsdl11Definition

Tags: java, spring, java-8, wsdl, wsdl2java

I have this issue:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'biller_customer_authentication' defined in class path resource [app/bbiller/billerblue/Config/BillerWebConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition]: Factory method 'billerCustomerAuthentication' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'billerCustomerAuthenticationSchema' defined in class path resource [app/bbiller/billerblue/Config/BillerWebConfig.class]: xsd 'class path resource [biller.xsd]' does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at app.bbiller.billerblue.BillerBlueApplication.main(BillerBlueApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition]: Factory method 'billerCustomerAuthentication' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'billerCustomerAuthenticationSchema' defined in class path resource [app/bbiller/billerblue/Config/BillerWebConfig.class]: xsd 'class path resource [biller.xsd]' does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'billerCustomerAuthenticationSchema' defined in class path resource [app/bbiller/billerblue/Config/BillerWebConfig.class]: xsd 'class path resource [biller.xsd]' does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at app.bbiller.billerblue.Config.BillerWebConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.billerCustomerAuthenticationSchema(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at app.bbiller.billerblue.Config.BillerWebConfig.billerCustomerAuthentication(BillerWebConfig.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at app.bbiller.billerblue.Config.BillerWebConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$billerCustomerAuthentication$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at app.bbiller.billerblue.Config.BillerWebConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at app.bbiller.billerblue.Config.BillerWebConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.billerCustomerAuthentication(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: xsd 'class path resource [biller.xsd]' does not exist
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:122) ~[spring-core-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema.afterPropertiesSet(SimpleXsdSchema.java:119) ~[spring-xml-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

this is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class BillerWebConfig {

    @Autowired
    private BillerCustomerAuthenticationService billerCustomerAuthenticationService;

    @Bean(name = "biller_customer_authentication")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition billerCustomerAuthentication() {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("BillerCustomerAuthenticationPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/biller_customer_authentication");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://localhost:8096");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(billerCustomerAuthenticationSchema());
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema billerCustomerAuthenticationSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("biller.xsd"));
    }
}
```

I try to create wsdl from xsd with spring I tried all the versions for JDK till I reach the 8 and still not working all versions above 8 not working even with 8 this is the issue

I was try to create a web service with spring boot project but it's not working